# React.js: Is there a way to apply a separate style to a component to be rendered in array.map?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

The following demo uses array.map to render three blocks.

[demo(CodeSandBox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cdn-x9h3d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The names of the colors are defined in `Colors.tsx`.

```
export default {
  foo: "#ff6347",
  bar: "#4682b4",
  baz: "#90ee90"
};
```

Is there a way to change the color of a block rendered by array.map individually using the color you defined?

I use [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) for CSS in JS.

---

Below is the entire code.

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/core";
import colors from "./Colors";

export default function App() {
  const colorName = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
  const Block = colorName.map((item, index) => {
    const blockStyle = css`
    ${baseStyle}
    background-color: ${colors.foo}; // ${colors.item} did not work.
  `;
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <span>{item}</span>
        <div css={blockStyle} />
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{Block}</ul>;
}

const baseStyle = css`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tldr

```
background-color: ${colors[item]};
```

---

colors is an object. `colorName => color`

To access a color by colorName you can use `colors[colorName]`

Thus in your code:

```
background-color: ${colors[colorName]}
```

or (since you named the colorName `item`)

```
background-color: ${colors[item]};
```

Comment: I gave the type to colors and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.